# Execute dynamic query without showing the result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamicquery

I have a stored procedure that returns results from several checks. Within the stored procedure I have dynamic queries. The first one is intended to calculate the last update date for a particular table. The result from this query should be saved in a variable which I will use further as single value, so I will not have to calculate it every time I need it.

The query looks like this:

```
SET @lastUpdate = ' (SELECT MAX(CAST(' + @column + ' as date)) FROM ' + @schema + '.' + @table + ')'
EXEC sp_executesql @lastUpdate
```

The problem is that when I run my stored procedure it returns the result from this query (for example 2021-01-31) and then it returns the results for the checks I make.
[image]

So what I want to do is to calculate `@lastUpdate` but not to show the result, just to use it. I tried with output variable but I got the same result.

Comment: As an aside; for safety you should be using [`QUOTENAME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) around your names.

Comment: I *hope* that those dynamic objects are being sanitised before you inject them; otherwise this is a huge security flaw.

Comment: I don't understand your question - assigning a value to a variable will never output the itself? But then the query you are showing isn't assigning a value, it *is* selecting it. So I expect your SP isn't working as intended. And you will have to use output parameters if you are calculating multiple values using dynamic SQL in order to get the values back into the calling context.

Comment: Why not use an `OUTPUT` parameter instead to assign the value to a variable, if you don't want to return the dataset to the application layer?

Comment: @Larnu, what do you mean sanitised? Also, I don't want to return the value of this query that I showed in my question. I tried using output variable, but when I run the stored procedure it still shows the result from this query.

Comment: Assigning variables, including using output parameters (correctly) will never be shown as results. You probably need to show us more code because as it stands its not clear. Sanitised means using something like `QUOTENAME` to prevent SQL injection attacks. The code you have shown *IS* a select - which returns a result. You probably intend to assign it to an output parameter.

Comment: @DaleK The rest of the code is not linked to this query. Thanks for the `QUOTENAME` suggestion. I will use it. But can you show me how to properly use the output parameter in this query?

Answer (score 2):

Reading between the lines, I think this might be what you are after, with an `OUTPUT` parameter:

```sql
--Your Dynamic Objects
DECLARE @Column sysname,
        @Schema sysname,
        @Table sysname;

DECLARE @LastUpdate date, --This isn't yor dynamic statement now, it's a date, like the name implies
        @SQL nvarchar(MAX); --This is your dynamic statement

SET @SQL = N'SELECT @LastUpdate = MAX(CAST(' + QUOTENAME(@Column) + N' as date)) FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@Schema) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@Table) + N';'
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, N'@LastUpdate date OUTPUT', @LastUpdate OUTPUT;

PRINT @LastUpdate; --Printing to demonstrate value has been assigned
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c85732336304dc5511d48506b2df6103)

Comment: Well, it works if I run it alone, thanks. If I run it in stored procedures I get the date result, followed by table result for my basic checks. I guess it is the way I output results from the stored procedure.

Comment: *"f I run it in stored procedures I get the date result, followed by table result for my basic checks"* The behaviour won't change if you run it in the procedure, @Yana .

Comment: I have edited my question and added a screenshot of the results I get after I execute the stored procedure. The first one is line coming from this dynamic query and the second is the one that I get from the other dynamic query I use in the usp.

Comment: The above doesn't return a dataset, @Yana . If you are getting the value, you are getting it from something else. This is what happens when you include partial code you don't understand, you implement incorrectly as we can't show you how.. Sounds like you have another `SELECT @LastUpdate;` somewhere.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot show more.. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Then you'll have to debug that yourself, @Yana . Again, the above does ***not*** return a dataset, so it is not producing the one you are seeing.